# UICollectionViewFlowLayout exception when executing XHR-Request in NativeScript

Tags: ios, xcode, typescript, xcode7, nativescript

I tried to execute an POST-Request to a given API via Xcode 7. My error is:

> the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
>
> The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f99fe411ea0>, and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f99fe411ea0>.
>   Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.

The code I tried to execute:

TypeScript:

```
makeRatingCall(userRating) {
    var score = userRating;
    var film_edition_id = "123456789";
    var computer_name = ConfigurationService.getUserData().user_username;
    var api_key = "key";
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "my-url" + this.formatParams({film_edition_id, score, computer_name, api_key }), true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).err_code);
            } else {
                reject(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.onerror = function( err ) {
            reject ( err );
        }
        xhr.send();
    });
}

formatParams = function ( params ){
    return "?" + Object.keys(params).map((key) => {
        return `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`
    }).join("&")
}

rateIt() {
    var translate = this.translateService;
    this.makeRatingCall( this.currentRating )
        .then(function ( err_code ) {
            if (err_code == 0) {
                dialogs.alert({
                    title: translate.instant("VOTE_SUCCESSFUL"),
                    message: translate.instant("VOTE_SUCCESSFUL_MSG"),
                    okButtonText: translate.instant("OK")
                });
                this.rateInteraction = false;
            } else if (err_code == 1) {
                dialogs.alert({
                    title: translate.instant("ALREADY_VOTED"),
                    message: translate.instant("ALREADY_VOTED_MSG"),
                    okButtonText: translate.instant("OK")
                });
            } else {
                dialogs.alert({
                    title: translate.instant("VOTE_FAILED"),
                    message: translate.instant("VOTE_FAILED_MSG"),
                    okButtonText: translate.instant("OK")
                });
            }
        } )
        .catch(function ( err ) {
            dialogs.alert({
                title: translate.instant("VOTE_FAILED"),
                message: translate.instant("VOTE_FAILED_MSG"),
                okButtonText: translate.instant("OK")
            }); 

        });
}
```

html:

```
        <GridLayout columns="*4,*,*,*,*,*" rows="*">
            <Button col="0" row="0" [text]="'SEND_RATING'|translate" class="send-rating-button" (onTap)="rateIt()"
            [isUserInteractionEnabled]="rateInteraction"></Button>
            <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[0] }}" col="1" row="0" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('1')"
                [isUserInteractionEnabled]="rateInteraction"></Image>
            <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[1] }}" col="2" row="0" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('2')"
                [isUserInteractionEnabled]="rateInteraction"></Image>
            <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[2] }}" col="3" row="0" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('3')"
                [isUserInteractionEnabled]="rateInteraction"></Image>
            <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[3] }}" col="4" row="0" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('4')"
                [isUserInteractionEnabled]="rateInteraction"></Image>
            <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[4] }}" col="5" row="0" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('5')"
                [isUserInteractionEnabled]="rateInteraction"></Image>
        </GridLayout>
```

css:

```
.send-rating-button {
    margin-top: 10;
    margin-left: 30;
    margin-right: 10;
    margin-bottom: 10;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.star-image {
    width: 30;
    margin: 10;
}
```

I am not sure how to handle this error, does anyone have a hint for me? :D

Comment: While using NativeScript Angular template I could suggest using the angular HTTP module, instead of XMLHttpRequest. An example of the usage of this module could be found here -  https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/http

Comment: Thanks for the comment but that does not change anything on the setting, since this seems to be a graphical issue

Comment: Looks there is no sufficient height for image & buttons in your grid layout. You can try to set height explicitly of grid layout to adjust

Comment: I tried it but that did not do the trick. I post an answer on how it works for me now, but I am not sure if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I used a `appSettings.setNumber(...);` in the `application-settings` module of my application. I changed it into `appSettings.setString();` and formatted the parameter into a String and now it worked. Let's see if that did really do the trick...